# Is $(\mathbb R^{+}, \oplus, \otimes)$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Is $(\mathbb R^{+}, \oplus, \otimes)$ a field? Note that $x \oplus y = xy$ and $x \otimes y = x^{\ln y}$ for $x,y \in\mathbb R^{+}$.

I have already proved that it is a ring and that it is commutative.

I also found out that the multiplicative identity is Euler's number $e.$

I do not know how to proceed in showing it is a field though.
My first thought is that it should be something like $x^{\ln z} = e = z^{\ln x}$ for $x \in \mathbb R^{+}$, where $z$ is the multiplicative inverse. But I'm struggling to find $z.$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @PrimeMover Note that the OP is using unusual definitions of "$+$" and "$*$" (see the first sentence of the body question).

Comment: @PrimeMover Of course it is a group.

Comment: Pleas use MathJax properly. It would be better if you use other symbols for your operations, since you are not using $+$ and $*$ in their standard meanings. Perhaps $\oplus$ (`\oplus`) and $\otimes$ (`\otimes`)?

Comment: @DonThousand Of course $*$ is commutative: $x*y=e^{\ln (x)\ln (y)}$.

Comment: @DonThousand it is commutative.

Comment: @PrimeMover don’t just read the title.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I have seen this exact same statement on this site. Maybe someone can find the duplicate.

Comment: This ring is isomorphic to $(\mathbb R,+,\times)$ with the usual operations.

Comment: Okay so the post was edited after I commented.

Comment: In general, if $(K,+,\times)$ is a field, and $f: X\to K$ is a bijection of sets, we can define a field $(X,\oplus,\otimes)$ defined, for $x,y\in X,$ $$x\oplus y =f^{-1}(f(x)+f(y))\\x\otimes y=f^{-1}(f(x)\times f(y))$$

Comment: @PrimeMover it clearly had the definitions of $+,*$ originally, but the notation change makes it clearer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I apologise. Feel free to go to the Customer Service desk, and you will be refunded in full.

Comment: Nobody is asking for an apology, but if you feel the need to apologize, just don’t do it again. (We’ve all done it. But your later comments seem to deny doing it.) @PrimeMover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove it's a field you additionally need to prove that each non-zero(non-additive identity) element has a multiplicative inverse.

$$x\otimes y = x^{\ln(y)}=e$$

So $\ln(y)\ln(x)=1\implies y = e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}$

Also $ e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}\otimes x=e^{(\frac{1}{\ln(x)})\ln(x)}=e$.

So each non-zero(additive identity) element $x\in R$ has inverse $e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}$.

Now note that the additive identity is $1$. As $x\oplus 1 =1\oplus x = x$.

Now as in a field , you cannot invert the additive identity. Here the inverse of $1$ does not exist as $e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}$ does not make sense at $x=1$ ( Compare this situation to when $\frac{1}{0}$ does not make sense in $\mathbb{R}$ with usual addition and multiplication. Here $1$ is playing the role of $0$ and $e$ is playing the role of $1$.

Also I forgot to mention. In order to complete the proof . You should also verify the associativity and distributive laws.

Comment: Note, $x=1$ doesn’t have a multiplicative inverse, and you should make a comment about why.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews From this answer and your comment, we have no multiplicative inverse for 1. Then it is not a division ring. Does that mean $R^{+}$ is not a field?

Comment: @cme No, every field has one element that has no multiplicative inverse. What is the identity of $\oplus?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It should be 1. Are additive identities somehow exempted from having a multiplicative inverse?

Comment: What's the inverse of $0$ in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: I have reread my textbook and there is this statement "every nonzero element in R should be a unit for R to be a division ring". Is the "nonzero" supposed to refer to the additive identity of an ordinary addition? Does this basically mean all elements that are not additive identity should be a unit?

Hence, in our case, all elements in $R^{+}$ not equal to 1 should be units for $R^{+}$ to be a division ring, making it a field?

Comment: @cme It is referring to the additive identity in your algebra. The real $0$ isn’t the additive identity here.

Comment: @cme . Sorry for such a late comment. I posted the answer at about 2 in the morning here in India. I have edited my answer and I hope you understand this better now.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  . I have edited as you suggested . I posted this answer at 2 in the morning.